# Isotope infinite scroll issues in chrome

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am using isotope to create a titled effect on a webpage - currently I use the default code from the isotope site to test the effects. Used the infinite scroll feature with code as mentioned on the isotope site(page source). I get the infinite scroll effects to work well on firefox but not on chrome. Is there something extra that needs to be done for chrome for infinite scroll to work?